# Wrong parameter value in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, closures

As you can see in local scope of the function, the value of `list` is an Array but when I type `list` in console it return a `DOM element.` I don't understand this behaviour.

[image]

Comment: In console `list` return with a ID of `list`. And if any variable declared inside a function,it only accessible by that function,it will not available outside of this function.

Comment: @MuhammadAmirozzamanNiaz When I hover on the variable it shows HTML element as the value.

Comment: @MattOestreich But you can see the scope in right panel, the value of list is an array.

Comment: Looks like the console expression is not evaluated in the scope of the function where you have stopped at the breakpoint.

Comment: I misunderstood your question at first.. it looks like you are manually typing `list` in your console, which @MuhammadAmirozzamanNiaz is correct, it does not get evaluated the same.. Inside your function, right before you do `list.map` you should put a `console.log(list)` so that it gets evaluated appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In console `list` return with a ID of `list`. And if any variable declared inside a function,it only accessible by that function,it will not available outside of this function. Please read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) doc to know further more about function

Answer (score 1):

Actually your list variable (which is inside the function) is in scoped with that function only. That's why you won't get the value of that variable globally (into your console) And that's why it's showing a different thing.